# Programmatically adding group to Site Collections

Tags: development, permissions

I am trying to create a user group in SharePoint using the following code:

```
// check if group exists
SPGroup newGroup = OfferWorkspaceUserGroup.GetGroup(web, name);

//create group with no users
if (newGroup == null) {
    //group does not exist -> create it
    web.SiteGroups.Add(name, owner, null, description);
    web.Update();
    newGroup = web.SiteGroups[name];
}
```

This code runs fine if the owner is the SharePoint Admin. If I set the owner to any normal user registered in the AD (that has access to the root site collection) the line

```
newGroup = web.SiteGroups[name];
```

throws an error saying that the group cannot be found.

However if I run the command `web.SiteGroups` I can see that the group exists.

I tried to give the owner full control which did not make a difference.

I am using C# and SharePoint 2013
Why am I seeing this behavior?

Comment: Can you please try your code in SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrievledge delegate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the user doesn't have permissions to view the group membership. I'm attaching my own version of the AddGroup method. Please note the grp.OnlyAllowMembersViewMembership = false which sets the option for other users to check the group membership. Also you can check if a user has permissions to see the membership using the [CanCurrentUserViewMembership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spgroup.cancurrentuserviewmembership%28v=office.15%29.aspx) property, this will avoid exceptions.

```
 private static void AddGroup(SPWeb web, SPRoleType roleType, string groupName)
    {
        var groups = web.SiteGroups;

        var userGroup = FindSiteGroup(web.Site, groupName);

        if (userGroup == null)
        {
            groups.Add(groupName, web.CurrentUser, null, string.Empty);
            web.AssociatedGroups.Add(web.SiteGroups[groupName]);
        }

        var grp = web.SiteGroups[groupName];
        grp.OnlyAllowMembersViewMembership = false;
        grp.Update();

        if (roleType != SPRoleType.None)
        {
            var asgn = new SPRoleAssignment(web.SiteGroups[groupName]);
            var roleDef = web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(roleType);
            asgn.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(roleDef);
            web.RoleAssignments.Add(asgn);
        }

        web.Update();
    }
```

-Hope it helps-

Comment: Thanks it helped as well as that I was ruining this code through a timer job which seemed to make additional trouble. The final solution was to put the code in to a featured which is the activated by the job. Took me quite a while to figure out that this code somehow can not be fun directly by the job.